# Rails is loading js inconsistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Pretty common problem: rails is loading js and jQuery pretty inconsistently due to turbolinks. Unfortunately stuff like `$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () { code });` is not doing the trick regarding consistency.

for example: if I got stuff running with coffee-script like rails slick slider everything is working fine, custom js I got in my asset tree is not loading consistently. When reloading a page the js is there, navigating via turbolinks makes script disappear/not loading sometimes.

I have this problem since the beginning of my rails career and just can't fix it. Even stuff like `<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">` has no impact. How can I get my script load 100% consistent?

I already tried `$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () { code });` and `<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">`

what can I do?

Comment: Do you really need turbolinks? I may have a solution if you want to remove it.

Comment: I really like the async like behavior and want to keep it ideally. But feel free to share your attempt

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to remove turbolinks to fix this, here is how you can do it;

In **application.js** remove `//= require turbolinks`

In **Gemfile** remove `gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'`

In application.html.erb remove `'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'` from both the `stylesheet_link_tag` and the `javascript_include_tag`

I ran into this same problem and I found that removing turbolinks was the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `$(document)` you can load jquery from CDN before the application.js in application.html.erb.
If you want to keep the turbolinks way you should use something like `window.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', ->`